# Cakephp read image from app/uploads directory

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.x

I am sending images from my mobile app to the server.

I am saving the images in the directory

```
app/uploads/image.png
```

and storing the path in the database.

I want to know how can I access this image from a browser. In short, what would be the URL of this image? I want to check first in the browser before I send the path to my mobile app

Comment: We are unable to be of much assistance with invisible code...

Comment: store images inside app/webroot directory

Comment: Is there a reason why you are uploading images outside the webroot? If you put them outside the webroot you will need to write code to serve them to the user which is possibly overkill if you don't need to do anything special like control access permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside discussions on whether the proposed approach is the correct one or not, I'm going to focus on a providing a solution to the problem raised.

In fact, it's quite easy. Add the following to one of your controllers:

```
public function download($filename){

    $file = APP."/uploads/{$filename}";
    $this->response->file($file);
    return $this->response;
}
```

<sub>Note: The code above lacks error handling.</sub>

You can then access

```
http://www.example.com/my_controller/download/my_picture.jpg
```

See

- [Cookboox 2.x | Request and Response objects | Sending files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files)

Comment: could you tell me what would be the good approach? I am handling user personal images, gallery, and other stuff

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have much to add to what has already been mentioned in the comments. Probably you have a good reason not to store your files under `/app/webroot/`. The above code should work. Not sure if it opens your app to security vulnerabilities (like trying to retrieve files from other folders, etc.). Just make sure you remove any path information that a malicious user may try to include in `$filename` (I'm unaware if such risk exists).

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Html->image('/uploads/image.png');
```

Comment: you can you this code to get the image from the upload folder in app/web-root/